# nginx container on host vm is not routing requests

Tags: docker, nginx, google-cloud-platform, containers

I am trying to host a webapp from a docker container on a GCP vm, via an nginx container on the vm.  But my requests are not getting routed to the webapp service, and I only see the nginx container welcome page.  My nginx.conf in the nginx docker is configured as below -

```
upstream app {
   least_conn;
   server 127.0.0.1:8020;}

upstream mysql {
   least_conn;
   server 127.0.0.1:3306;}



server {
    listen       80;
    server_name appServer1;
    
    location / {
        proxy_pass   http://app;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    }

    location /mysql {
        proxy_pass   http://mysql;
    }



}
```

I start the 3 containers independently (and do not use docker-compose) in the order - mysql, app, nginx to handle dependencies.  My running containers are somewhat as shown below -

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                COMMAND                  CREATED        STATUS                 PORTS                                       NAMES
999999999999   api:latest     "python3 API.py"         8 hours ago    Up 2 hours             0.0.0.0:8001->8020/tcp, :::8001->8020/tcp   api_c
999999999666   nginx:latest   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   11 hours ago   Up 2 hours             0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, :::80->80/tcp           nginx_c
999999999111   999999999991         "/entrypoint.sh mysq…"   40 hours ago   Up 2 hours (healthy)   3306/tcp, 33060-33061/tcp                   mysql_c
```

What might be wrong ?

Adding the Dockerfiles as well..

```
nginx dockerfile
*****************
FROM nginx
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
EXPOSE 80
STOPSIGNAL SIGTERM
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]

app Dockerfile
**************
FROM alpine:latest
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN apk add --no-cache python3-dev \
   && apk add py3-pip \
   && apk add build-base  \ 
   && pip3 install --upgrade pip \
   && pip3 install -r requirements.txt --ignore-installed --no-cache-dir \
   && apk add mysql mysql-client
EXPOSE 8020  
ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]
CMD ["API.py"]

mysql Dockerfile
****************
FROM mysql/mysql-server:8.0
RUN chown -R mysql:root /var/lib/mysql/
ARG MYSQL_DATABASE
ARG MYSQL_USER
ARG MYSQL_PASSWORD
ARG MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
ENV MYSQL_DATABASE=$MYSQL_DATABASE
ENV MYSQL_USER=$MYSQL_USER
ENV MYSQL_PASSWORD=$MYSQL_PASSWORD
ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD

COPY data.sql /etc/mysql/data.sql
RUN sed -i 's/MYSQL_DATABASE/'$MYSQL_DATABASE'/g' /etc/mysql/data.sql
EXPOSE 3306
```

Comment: What do you get for netstat command below? Do you see your api port/s listening? "netstat -an | grep -i listen"

Comment: Also bump your error_log to debug. Do you get any details in log? 
        "error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;"

Comment: netstat gives -->                                                                                                         tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8001            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::8001                 :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                   LISTEN

Comment: Since nothing is listening on 8020 you need to adjust your NGINX config to point to 8001 if that is in-fact your api server.

Comment: I think, a minimal reproducible example would go a long way here. If the app and mysql upstreams are in the different containers (different from nginx), you shouldn't be using the 127.0.0.1 for their servers, unless you are also using the `host_network`. Want to add your Dockerfile too?

Comment: @SmileIT, access.log as well as app container log gives 304 error ..."GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 0 and Yes, I changed NGINX config to point to 8001 (i.e, 3rd line as server 127.0.0.1:8001;} ).  But still no luck...

Comment: @jabbson, Yes, I am using 3 separate containers for app, mysql and nginx.  But why do you say I should not be using 127.0.0.1 ?  Also have provided the dockerfiles at the end of my original qn.

Comment: @bkrishna2006 because if the `app` is not in the same container (as in not in nginx container), and instead is in another pod, this other pod will have its own ip, and cannot be referenced as 127.0.0.1